# Boost variant and visitor

Tags: c++, boost

I have 2 structures Base and Derived and boost:variant with 2 types.

```
struct Base : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
    virtual void operator(Type1& t) {}
    virtual void operator(Type2& t) {}
};
```

What I want to do is do define Derived as:

```
struct Derived : public Base
{
    void operator(Type1& t) { /*some impl*/ }
};
```

I do not override operator for the Type2 assuming it is defined in Base and empty.

For some reason if I write

```
Derived visitor;
boost::apply_visitor(visitor, variant);
```

I get
error: no match for call to '(Derived) (Type2&)'

Of course, if I add operator for Type2 into derived it works ok.
Could anyone please help to understand why it is not working without adding operator for Type2?

Comment: `virtual void operator(Type1& t) {}` is not valid syntax. What did you _actually_ write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name lookup doesn't consider operators in base classes. You need to explicitly bring it in `Derived`'s scope for it to be seen by name lookup:

```
struct Derived : public Base
{
    void operator()(Type1& t) { /*some impl*/ }
    using Base::operator();
};
```

Comment: Did not know that! Thanks!